# Access a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have seen several examples of how to load a file with javascript, however most of those examples use the data from the file to display it in a html.

I need to keep accessing a file since the file keeps updating and use those values in javascript as variables.

I got the closest with this,

```
function test() {

    $().ready(function(){ 
        var url = 'output.txt';
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            // can use 'data' in here...
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

It logs document to the console and I can collapse that.

There is really a lot of stuff (to much to list here). I only don't know in what kind of format it needs the data to be or how to access it.  I do see stuff about xml-stylesheet, so can i even use this?

Changing the way I write the file is no problem for me.

Comment: Have you tried [JSON](http://www.json.org/)?

Comment: json would be the easiest to parse, as the file keeps changing would wrapping the `$.get...` in a loop work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a [JSON file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).  For example:

```
{
  username: "Rocket",
  realname: "Eric",
  age: 23
}
```

To read this, you can use jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

```
$.getJSON('/path/to/your/file.json', function(data){
    var username = data.username;
});
```

You can also use [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), though I suggest using JSON (it's easier to get the data from it).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<item> <!-- XML needs a root element -->
  <username>Rocket</username>
  <realname>Eric</realname>
  <age>23</age>
</item>
```

jQuery doesn't have a `$.getXML` method, so we have to use [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$.get('/path/to/your/file.xml', function(data){
    var username =  $('item', data).find('username').text();
}, 'xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Jquery GetJson method: Something like this. May need some tweaking.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.yourfile.html',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){

  $('#yourdiv').html(data);

  }
});
```

Comment: Setting the HTML to the JSON data isn't going to do anything useful.  Depending on the JSON, you'd want something like `data.html` or whatever.